# How to know the RSS Feed URL of my moodle site

Tags: rss, feed, moodle

I cant find any help to let me guess the rss feed url of forums on my moodle site.

Is there any particular pattern? like in wordpress we can type sitename.com/feed but in moodle it seems very much complicated and is frustating.

I have setup a discussion forum inside a course, and enabled rss feed, But I'm just lost to know where is the rss feed of that forum??

Also there is nothing i can find on moodle forum for rss feed url except this http://etfinpro.ardortech.com/rss/file.php/  which have no clue where should i go :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site admin > Advanced features > Enable RSS feeds

Site admin > Plugins > Activity modules > Forum > Enable RSS feeds

Inside the forum activity, click 'Edit settings', then RSS > RSS feed for this activity: Posts / Discussions; RSS > Number of RSS recent articles: 5 (or anything greater than 0).

Save & view the activity, then look for 'RSS feed of posts' (or 'RSS feed for discussions') in the 'Administration' block (under 'Forum administration').

Comment: thanks, i was able to find the url , but that contains secret key related to the user. How can i make it a public feed so that even guest can see the feed ? Also isn't there any way i can setup a single sitewide forum for all ?? not course wise??

Comment: You can set up a single forum by adding it to the front page course - https://docs.moodle.org/en/Front_page_settings . RSS feeds are protected, as that means you can revert a user's permissions and the RSS feed will no longer have access to the forum. However, you could always publish the RSS feed, including the user token.